# vba end if without block if

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting this error, but can't figure out why. It looks like all rules are followed.

The structure as I read is the following - If -> ElseIf -> End If. But here I get an error though it's all the same.

```
Sub hide()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim wRange As Range
        Set wRange = Range("A5:B10")

        Dim mergedRows As Integer
        Dim mergedColumns As Integer

        Dim cellFirst As Range

        For Each cell In wRange
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf cell.MergeCells Then
                mergeRows = cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count
                mergeColumns = cell.MergeArea.Columns.Count
                With cell.MergeArea
                    Set cellFirst = cell.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1))
                    If IsEmpty(cellFirst) Then
                        cellFirst.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: type `End With` right before the last `End If`. In this case the error message is misleading, because the `With` block is the issue, not the `If`, but over time (and with good indenting practice, as you have done) you'll spot these much faster and know what to look for :)

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, Thanks! Didn't know With out to be finished too. You might answer, I'll accept.

Comment: you can actually remove the `With cell.MergeArea` as you never implement a proper With block. (nor do you need to).

Answer (score 2):

You need to also close your **With** statement.

```
With cell.MergeArea
   Set cellFirst = cell.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1))
   If IsEmpty(cellFirst) Then
      cellFirst.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End If
End With
```